# JavaFx close window on pressing esc not working on table view?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I've used the following function to close the `Stage` when pressing escape key. It works fine but it doesn't work when my table has the keyboard focus.

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() 
{
  @Override
  public void handle(KeyEvent evt) 
  {
     if(evt.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ESCAPE))
     {
        dialogStage.close();
     }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the `KeyEvent` event is being consumed by the child node `TableView`. So the right approach will be attaching `EventFilter` instead of `EventHandler`:

```
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ESCAPE)) {
            stage.close();
        }
    }
});
```

To see the difference between event handlers and filters refer to [Handling JavaFX Events](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/jfxpub-events.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but found the target of `KeyEvent` is the `TableView`, not parent stage, that is why the parent doesn't get `Esc` event.

My variant based on `EventHandler` ([bubbling phase](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/handlers.htm)):

```
myTable.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
        stage.close();
    }
});
```